# Can any one tell me what is the error in below code related to storing data into sqlite in android

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite

**activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/fl1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/imgback"
        android:src="@drawable/background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@string/back"/>
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ll1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10sp"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:hint="@string/Uname"
        android:id="@+id/eduname"
        />
    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:hint="@string/Pword"
        android:id="@+id/edpword"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <CheckBox 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:text="@string/checkboxtxt"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imglogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/imgbt"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/checkbox"
        android:onClick="login"
        android:src="@drawable/loginkey" />
    </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rl2"
        android:gravity="end"
        >
         <ImageButton 
          android:id="@+id/imgsignup"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvnotamem"
          android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/tvnotamem"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:contentDescription="@string/imgsignup"         
          android:onClick="signup"
          android:src="@drawable/sign_up"/>


         <TextView
             android:id="@+id/tvnotamem"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_centerVertical="true"
             android:text="@string/notamem" />

                  </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.login;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

EditText eduname,edpword;
CheckBox checkbox;
ImageButton imglogin,imgsignup;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();
}

public void init()
{
    eduname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eduname);
    edpword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edpword);
}

public void login(View v)
{

}
public void signup(View v)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(this,SignUp.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
}
```

**SignUp.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp"
    android:baselineAligned="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background1">
    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:id="@+id/edrname"
        android:hint="@string/edrname"/>
    <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:id="@+id/edrpword"
        android:hint="@string/edrpword"/>
      <EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:id="@+id/edrconfrmpword"
        android:hint="@string/edrconfrmpword"/>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/edphoto"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:hint="@string/edbrowsehint"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btnbrowse"
        android:text="@string/btnbrowse"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="browse"/>
</LinearLayout>
      <Button android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:id="@+id/submit"
          android:onClick="submit"
          android:textSize="24sp"
          android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
          android:text="@string/submit"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

**SignUp.java**

```
package com.example.login;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class SignUp extends Activity{

static EditText runame,rpword,rconfpword,edphoto;
SQLiteDatabase db;
String addrsoffile;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.signup);
    init();
}
public void init()
{
    runame=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edrname);
    rpword=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edrpword);
    rconfpword=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edrconfrmpword);
    edphoto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edphoto);
}
public void browse(View v){

    Intent i = new Intent(this,FileChooser.class);
    startActivityForResult(i,1);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(requestCode == 1)
    {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            addrsoffile = data.getStringExtra("GetFileName");
            edphoto.setText(addrsoffile);
        }
    }
}
public void submit(View v)
{
    Intent i = new Intent(this,DataHelper.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
}
```

**DataBaseHandler.java**

```
package com.example.login;

public class DataBaseHandler {

String uname,pword,confpword;

public DataBaseHandler(){

}
public DataBaseHandler(String uname,String pword,String confpword){
    this.uname = uname;
    this.pword = pword;
    this.confpword = confpword;
}
public String getUname() {
    return uname;
}

public void setUname(String uname) {
    this.uname = uname;
}

public String getPword() {
    return pword;
}

public void setPword(String pword) {
    this.pword = pword;
}

public String getConfpword() {
    return confpword;
}

public void setConfpword(String confpword) {
    this.confpword = confpword;
}

}
```

**DataHelper.java**

```
package com.example.login;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DataHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String Database_Name = "LoginDetails.db";
    public static final int Database_Version = 1;
    public static final String Table_Name = "Registration";
    int idno = 1;
    DataBaseHandler dbh;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Context c;

    public DataHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
            int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.c = context;
        dbh = new DataBaseHandler((SignUp.runame).getText().toString(), (SignUp.rpword).getText().toString(), (SignUp.rconfpword).getText().toString());
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String Sqlquery = "Create table if not exists "+Table_Name+" ("+idno+" integer primary key autoincrement,"+ " uname text not null,"+ " pword text not null,"+" confpword text not null)";
        db.execSQL(Sqlquery);
        insertEntry(dbh.uname, dbh.pword, dbh.confpword);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("Drop table if Exists "+Table_Name);

    }
    public void insertEntry(String uname,String pword,String cnfrmpword)
    {
        ContentValues val = new ContentValues();
        val.put("uname", uname);
        val.put("pword", pword);
        val.put("cnfrmpword", cnfrmpword);
        db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(Table_Name, null, val);
        Toast.makeText(c, "Data inserted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

I got an error at submit button click in SignUp.
when I am trying to execute it. I was unable to understand it.

So If any one help me I  will be great full and thanks in advance.

Comment: An explicit intent can only launch an activity - DataHelper isn't one.

Comment: Create object of your helper class and access that methods

Comment: I have created an object to Date Helper class instead of intending it. now there is no error and I can display a toast message also but, when I am opening the DDMS tab I was unable to find any stored file. 

changed code in submit button 
public void submit(View v)
 {
  new DataHelper(getApplicationContext(), DataHelper.Database_Name, null, DataHelper.Database_Version);
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Data stored successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  
 } @Nilesh

Comment: @Nilesh : Tell me the solution na.????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In submit button of SignUp class startActivity calls SQLiteOpenHelper class it is not correct it should call an Activity class.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code , it may Help you for Sign up

Add this code in your Sign up page for Inserting to Sqlite

```
private EditText fname, lname, email, phone, pass, cpass;
    private Button Save;

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sign_up);
        // for Database
        dbHelper = new DataBaseConnector_forsignUp(this);

        Signup = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        fname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        lname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        phone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        cpass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);

        Save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Save.setOnClickListener(this);

}

     public void onClick(View v) {
                // get Internet status
                isInternetPresent = cd1.isConnectingToInternet();
                switch (v.getId()) {

                case R.id.button1:

           String firstname = fname.getText().toString();
            String lastname = lname.getText().toString();
            String Email = email.getText().toString();
            String phonenumber = phone.getText().toString();
            String password = pass.getText().toString();
            String confpassword = cpass.getText().toString();

            DataBaseConnector_forsignUp dbconnector = new DataBaseConnector_forsignUp(this);

                            long id = dbconnector.insertData(firstname, lastname, Email,
                                    phonenumber, password, status);

        break;
        }
    }
```

DataBaseHelper_forsignUp.java

```
public class DataBaseHelper_forsignUp extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_FNAME = "firstname";
    public static final String KEY_LNAME = "lastname";
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String KEY_PHONENUMBER = "Phonenumber";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "Password";
    public static final String KEY_CONFPASSWORD = "ConfPassword";
    public static final String KEY_UPDATESTATUS = "Status";


    public static final String KEY_DATEOFBIRTH="Dateofbirth";

    public static final String KEY_LOCATION="Location";
    public static final String KEY_ADDRESS="Address";

    private static  String DATABASE_NAME = "Signup";
    public static String TABLE_NAME = "SIGNUP";


    // public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public DataBaseHelper_forsignUp(Context context, String name,
            CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, version);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String createQuery = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "("
                + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + " firstname TEXT NOT NULL," 
                + " lastname TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + " email TEXT NOT NULL," 
                + " Phonenumber TEXT NOT NULL,"
                + " Password TEXT NOT NULL," 
                + " Dateofbirth TEXT ,"
                + " Location TEXT ,"
                + " Address TEXT ,"
                + " Status TEXT NOT NULL);";


        db.execSQL(createQuery);


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

DataBaseConnector_forsignUp.java

```
public class DataBaseConnector_forsignUp 
{

     static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
     static final String KEY_FNAME = "Firstname";
     static final String KEY_LNAME = "Lastname";
     static final String KEY_EMAIL = "Email";
     static final String KEY_PHONENUMBER = "Phonenumber";
     static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "Password";
     static final String KEY_CONFPASSWORD = "ConfPassword";
     static final String KEY_UPDATESTATUS = "Status";



    public static final String KEY_DATEOFBIRTH="Dateofbirth";
    public static final String KEY_LOCATION="Location";
    public static final String KEY_ADDRESS="Address";


    private static  String DATABASE_NAME = "Signup";
    public static String TABLE_NAME = "SIGNUP";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public  SQLiteDatabase database;
    private DataBaseHelper_forsignUp dbOpenHelper;

    public static String email12="";

    public DataBaseConnector_forsignUp(Context context) 
    {
        dbOpenHelper = new DataBaseHelper_forsignUp(context, DATABASE_NAME, null,
                DATABASE_VERSION);

    }



        public  DataBaseConnector_forsignUp open() throws SQLException 
        {
            database = dbOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            return this;
        }

        /*// Close Database function
        public void close() 
        {
            if (dbOpenHelper != null)
                dbOpenHelper.close();
        }*/

        public void close() 
        {
            database.close();
        }

        public  SQLiteDatabase getDatabaseInstance()
        {
            return database;
        }

        //inserting the data to db
    public long insertData(String firstname, String lastname, String email,String phonenumber,String password,String status) 
    {
SQLiteDatabase db = dbOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DataBaseConnector_forsignUp.KEY_FNAME, firstname);
        values.put(DataBaseConnector_forsignUp.KEY_LNAME, lastname);
        values.put(DataBaseConnector_forsignUp.KEY_EMAIL, email);
        values.put(DataBaseConnector_forsignUp.KEY_PHONENUMBER, phonenumber);
        values.put(DataBaseConnector_forsignUp.KEY_PASSWORD, password);

        open();


        long id = db.insert(DataBaseConnector_forsignUp.TABLE_NAME, null , values);
        close();
        return id;
    }
    }
```